# Why doesn't spring-boot connect to local mysql server?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Cant get springboot connected to my localhost mysql database.
**This is my project structure:**

[image]

**This is the error-log.**

[image]

It is strange that he says: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)", but in my **application.properties** i have written connection:

```
server.port=8080
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.groovy.template.cache=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=stepin
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**My build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'databaseaccess'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    runtime("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I am new with springboot, but i can connect to my local database, when i write normal java connection, so why springboot cant?

Comment: Access denied suggests that the problem isn't Spring Boot.  You haven't GRANTed permission to connect in MySQL.

Comment: have you checked that you are loading the properties correctly into your persistence unit?

Comment: try with `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`

Comment: Oh my god... Nicolas thank you... it works now ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is because of these properties:

```
spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=stepin
```

Try to replace them by

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=stepin
```

It's possible to have 2 different users for executing [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) operations. You specified the second and didn't provide the first.

Quote from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/appendix-application-properties.adoc:

```
spring.datasource.data= # Data (DML) script resource reference.
spring.datasource.data-username= # User of the database to execute DML scripts (if different).
spring.datasource.data-password= # Password of the database to execute DML scripts (if different).
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password= # Login password of the database.
```

Comment: Really? ... It works and i have googled sooo much. this little mistake ... Well thank you!